# In excel, how to use an array formula to sum a range to offsets of itself, generating a new "sum" range?

Tags: excel

I'd like to use an array formula to sum a range to multiple offsets of itself:  for example, given the following range: {3,4,5,6,7} (say in cells A1:A5), I'd like to get the range added to itself, say 4 times, but each addition is offset by one column.  So the answer would be a range equal to {3, 3+4, 3+4+5, 3+4+5+6, 3+4+5+6+7, 4+5+6+7, 5+6+7, 6+7, 7}

Here is an example, offset by rows:

3

4 3

5 4 3

6 5 4 3

7 6 5 4 3

0 7 6 5 4

0 0 7 6 5

0 0 0 7 6

0 0 0 0 7

 =

3

7

12

18

25

22

18

13

7

Comment: Im confused... if you have the list as it is then you simply could use `SUM(A1:E1)` and drag it down. If you have only {3,4,5,6,7}, then start at row 5 (leaving row 1 to 4 empty and start with 3 at row 5) and somewhere late with the formula `=SUM(A1:A5)` and drag it down. And if you want to simply sum all up then it would just be a sum of all values multiplied by the count of numbers... so it is not clear to me what you really have and need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following in your first desired cell:

```
=IF(ROW(1:1)< COUNT($1:$1)*2,SUM(INDEX($1:$1,IF(ROW(1:1)<COUNT($1:$1),1,ROW(1:1)-COUNT($1:$1)+1)):INDEX($1:$1,MIN(ROW(1:1),COUNT($1:$1)))),"")
```

Then copy down. As numbers are added or subtracted from the first row the answer will change to match.  Just copy down sufficient rows to cover twice the greatest number of values in row 1.

[image: ![enter image description here]